# from terminal, open a local html file in a new background tab in safari

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, safari, tabs

Currently, in terminal, I use `open sample.html` command to open sample.html in the foreground.

But I would like safari to open one tab in the background and open sample.html in that tab.

ps:

`background` may have 2 meanings:

1. "the new tab is not in front of other tabs"
2. "safari itself is not in front of other apps".

Here I are referring to Meaning 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in terminal:

```
osascript myapplescript.app my_url
```

in myapplescript.app:

```
on openUrlInTheBackground(my_URL)
    tell application "Safari"
        tell window 1
            make new tab at end of tabs with properties {URL:my_URL}
        end tell
    end tell
end openUrlInTheBackground

on run argv
    set my_URL to (item 1 of argv)
    openUrlInTheBackground(my_URL)
end run
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to re-open another tab after you've opened `sample.html`? Then you can just `open sample.html && open foreground.html`

Comment: no. let's say currently safari is showing "foreground.html" tab, then I want to open "sample.html" in another background tab while safari still shows "foreground.html"

Comment: I'm not sure if you can accomplish this with the generic open command, but effectively what I said will accomplish this, only `foreground.html` is reloaded in this case. Also I assume that sample.html wasn't open to begin with, otherwise this will also just reload in this case.

What you could also try is to pass some parameters to a javascript on foreground.html that reloads another (background) target (tab) like `open foreground.html\?reload\=sample` while keeping foreground active.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. foreground.html is a page from internet like google search result page, so I cannot add js into it.  What I am thinking is, from command line, call a applescript who does the real job.